# Consulta sql server, Mostror los jugadores que hayan jugado todos los partidos de su equipo

Tags: sql, sql-server, server

Tengo esta Base de datos creada en sql server :

```
create database competicion

use competicion

create table equipo(
    id_equipo int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    pais varchar(50) not null,
    entrenador varchar(60) not null
)

create table jugador(
    id_jugador int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    id_equipo int not null,
    nombre varchar(60) not null,
    puesto varchar(60) not null,
    constraint fk_jugador_equipo foreign key (id_equipo) references equipo(id_equipo)
)

create table partido(
    id_partido int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    id_equipo1 int not null,
    id_equipo2 int not null,
    fecha date not null,
    constraint fk_partido_equipo1 foreign key (id_equipo1) references equipo(id_equipo),
    constraint fk_partido_equipo2 foreign key (id_equipo2) references equipo(id_equipo)
)

create table alineacion(
    id_partido int not null,
    id_equipo int not null,
    id_jugador int not null,
    dorsal int not null,
    constraint pk_alineacion primary key (id_partido, id_equipo, id_jugador),
    constraint fk_alineacion_partido foreign key (id_partido) references partido(id_partido),
    constraint fk_alineacion_equipo foreign key (id_equipo) references equipo(id_equipo),
    constraint fk_alineacion_jugador foreign key (id_jugador) references jugador(id_jugador)
)
```

Y necesito hacer la siguiente consulta:

Mostrar los nombres de los jugadores que hayan jugado todos los partidos de su equipo

lo que estoy intentando hacer es:

```
/*obtengo todos los partidos que jugo un jugador*/
select count(*) as partidos from alineacion group by id_jugador
```

```
/*Obtengo todos los partidos que jugaron los equipos1*/
select id_equipo1 from partido where id_equipo1 in (select id_equipo from equipo) group by id_equipo1
```

```
/*Obtengo todos los partidos que jugaron los equipos2*/
select id_equipo2 from partido where id_equipo2 in (select id_equipo from equipo) group by id_equipo2
```

Pero no se como juntar todo esto para mostrar los jugadores que jugaron todos los partidos de su equipo

si alguien pudiera ayudarme por favor se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Esto parece una tarea de escuela ¿Qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: Qué bien que estés comenzando en este mundo! Te sugiero que leas y te documentes en lo siguiente: "JOIN" para realizar una consulta en la que incluyes varias tablas (alineacion, equipo, partido,etc) luego con la función agregada "COUNT" puedes contar... y "GROUP BY" para agruparlos

Comment: Lo de los joins si lo manejo bien pero donde tengo problemas es en obtener la cantidad de todos los partidos jugados por cada equipo y compararlos con todos los partidos que ha jugado un determinado jugador en su equipo, no se como estructurar esa consulta

Comment: Muestra qué consultas has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: `select count(") from alineacion group by id_jugador` Con esto obtengo todos los partidos de todos los jugadores, ahora con esto: `select id_equipo1 from partido where id_equipo1 in (select id_equipo from equipo ) group by id_equipo1 ` Obtengo todos los partidos del los equipos1 y con esto: `select id_equipo2 from partido where id_equipo2 in (select id_equipo from equipo ) group by id_equipo1` encuentro todos los partidos que hayan jugado los equipos2, pero no se como juntar todo esto para encontrar los jugadores que han jugado todos los partidos que ha jugado su equipo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no has puesto datos de ejemplo, no he probado la consulta, pero sería algo así:

```
select *
from jugador j 
where not exists
(
  select * 
  from partido p
  where (p.id_equipo1 = j.id_equipo or p.id_equipo2 = j.id_equipo) 
  and not exists
  (
    select * 
    from alineacion a
    where a.id_partido = p.id_partido
    and a.id_jugador = j.id_jugador
  )
)
```

Básicamente lo que hace la consulta es devolver todos los jugadores, salvo aquellos de los que encuentre un partido de su equipo que él no ha jugado (es decir, que no existe ninguna alineación de ese partido con su id_jugador).

Si encuentra algún partido de su equipo que él no ha jugado, es que no ha jugado todos los partidos y por lo tanto no muestra ese jugador.

Dicho esto, si hubieses proporcionado algunos datos de ejemplo, podríamos ejecutar la consulta y comprobar que funciona.

Comment: Gracias, si funciona la consulta, he entendido claramente lo que indicaste en tu respuesta